# Can not install deSolve for for R version 3.6.2?

Tags: r

I'm trying to install the deSolve package in R by using install.packages("deSolve")

and it returned the error message:
package ‘deSolve’ is not available (for R version 3.6.2).

Also tried installing through other packages that contain deSolve as dependency, same error occurred:

Warning in install.packages :
dependency ‘deSolve’ is not available

I'm wondering is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: The current version of `deSolve` requires `R 4.0` as documented on the [CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/package=deSolve). You seem to be running an older version (`R 3.6`). You should either update your R, or install an older version of the package from the archive.

Comment: A backport patch of **deSolve** was submitted yesterday to CRAN, making it again compatible with R 3.6.0. Binary versions for Windows and MacOS will [show up](https://cran.r-project.org/package=deSolve) during the next days.